# Spring url mapping does not work

Tags: java, spring, url, servlets

I have a problem with my url mappings in Spring MVC. My goal is to map a url with this form: "applicationName/app/".

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "app/1")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test1 (){
        return "test1";
    }
}
```

I tried "/app/1" and "/app/1/", but my url mapping does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your dispatcher configured the way it is your mapping would be

```
{contextPath}/app/app/1
```

Answer (score 1):

In your web.xml you are using `/app/*` and again in your Controller you have given `app/1`..so 2 `app` is coming in your url mapping.So try to hit `appName/app/app/1` it should work.Otherwise remove the `app` from web.xml